# The exit stamp on the Schengen area with a transfer flight

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps

When you enter the Schengen area with a transfer flight, you get the stamp at the first entry point. For example if you depart from Beijing and arrive at Rome with Warsaw as a transit, you get the stamp at the border control of Warsaw Airport.

However, how about when you exit out of the Schengen? Suppose that you depart from Rome and arrive at Beijing with Warsaw as a transit, do you get the exit stamp at Warsaw, or Rome? And in this case, is my passport checked only in one border control?

---

*The potential situation why this matters:*

Suppose that I have a working and holiday visa for France, and stay there for 1 year. Then I finally get out of France, but since the direct flight is expensive I decide to buy a ticket to Beijing with Frankfurt as a transfer. In this case, if it is at the Frankfurt border control that my passport is checked, I would likely get caught as overstaying. So I must make sure it must be in France where my passport is checked; otherwise I must use a direct flight.

Comment: It's not that hard to imagine how this all works if you keep in mind that the people on any plane must be, for the purpose of immigration checks, either all in the Schengen area or all outside of it.  Therefore you do not leave the Schengen area before a flight between two Schengen airports.  Also, as Henning Makholm notes, German immigration officers also pay attention to French visas. That is integral to the correct functioning of the Schengen agreement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Exit checks would happen at the place where you *cross the external Schengen border* -- that is, Frankfurt in your case.

However, that doesn't mean you would be overstaying, since time spent in France under a French D visa or residence permit *does not count for the Schengen clock*.  The Schengen rules require each country to recognize the other member states' long-stay visas and residence permits for this purpose.

At the border checks in Frankfurt you would just point to your French visa, and everything will be alright.  If you want to be completely crazy-prepared, carry evidence that you have indeed spent the time in France, such as receipts for accommodation, payslips, or even grocery receipts. (And of course, hold on to the boarding pass for your flight from France *to* Frankfurt).